# Warning while running Airflow API to Trigger DAGs

Tags: python, airflow, pymysql

I am following this https://github.com/teamclairvoyant/airflow-rest-api-plugin Repository to work on Airflow Dags.
 . This contains API endpoints to Pause/Unpause/List_all/Trigger DAGs.
Whenever we run an API endpoint we get response in JSON format. I don't get any warning while running Pause/Unpause/List_all API endpoints, but when Running Trigger Endpoint I see a Warning.

JSON response when **PAUSE** API Endpoint is called.

```
{"airflow_cmd":"airflow pause airflow_sample",
"arguments":{
"api":"pause",
"dag_id":"airflow_sample"},
"call_time":"Wed, 05 Feb 2020 12:27:28 GMT",
"http_response_code":200,
"output":{
"stderr":"",
"stdin":"",
"stdout":"Dag: airflow_sample, paused: True\n"},
"post_arguments":{},
"response_time":"Wed, 05 Feb 2020 12:33:45 GMT",
"status":"OK"}
```

JSON response when **TRIGGER** API is called :

```
{"airflow_cmd":"airflow trigger_dag airflow_sample",
"arguments":{
"api":"trigger_dag",
"dag_id":"airflow_sample"},
"call_time":"Wed, 05 Feb 2020 12:27:28 GMT",
"http_response_code":200,
"output":{
"stderr":"/home/bhanuprakash/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py:170: Warning: (1300, \"Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '800495'\")\n  result = self._query(query)\n",
"stdin":"",
"stdout":""},
"post_arguments":{},
"response_time":"Wed, 05 Feb 2020 12:34:23 GMT",
"status":"OK"}
```

As you can see clearly when Trigger API endpoint is called I get **stderr**.
Is it something to do with MySQL? I am confused.

**PS:**
It was a Warning but not an Error. Does that effect the Result?

Comment: It is not an error but a warning. It must be related to the mysql query you are running. Make sure you are not using a not valid character your selected encoding.

Comment: I just called an API endpoint and I don't know what's wrong with that mysql query. That cursors.py file was downloaded when installing MySQL.